# Adding New and Featured Products to the home page in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, widget, magento-1.7

I've been Googling for a way to do this and, apologies if I'm wrong, but from what I can see the "{{block type="catalog....etc" method of adding new and featured products to the homepage of a Magento store no longer works in newer versions on Magento? It crashes my store at any rate.  EDIT: heres a link to the sort of thing I've been trying: [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/add_featured_products_to_home_page)

I've also attempted to use the built in widgets which dont crash the store but also dont display any content - I have followed quite a few tutorials to do this (and I've avoided little mistakes like not updating the product attributes etc) but still no success.

Is there any way of going about this without forking out for a paid pluggin? I've been looking at similar discussions on here but many are quite old and offer the 'block type' thing as a solution.

This is my first go with Magento so the answer may be staring me in the face but I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your store could be crashing because your application is running out of memory. Have you tried increasing the php memory limit?

Comment: Hi I'm not so sure that this is the reason - its only crashing from the point where I add the 'block' code but I'll give it a go and see if it does anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is free extension for this by **Inchoos**.
Check out this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-products-4605.html)

Comment: Hi, Yes I've attempted to use that extension too but it doesn't seem to be compatible with the lastest version of Magento - I've installed it but in the admin panel it just throws up an error; - just noticed that some of the ones who have left a review at the link you posted have found the same problem.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the method you used to display featured products and occured error.It will be easy to suggest a solution

Comment: Hi I've updated the post with a link to one of the tutorials I've tried (that caused the error) but I've just noticed it says at the very bottom of the article that it is out of date for 1.7 onwards and directs to a paid option... ultimately I guess I'll have to go for that but I'm just wondering if theres a free alternative. Its looking unlikely!

Comment: I just tried first method from the link you posted and it worked fine in magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: I've tried it on two sites now and neither have worked - the only thing the two sites have in common is that I used the same theme extension as a starting point for developing my own theme (mobile shopee) so could this be part of the problem? I've noticed that when I call products from a category that is empty it displays a message but when I call from a category which does contain products it crashes from that point down (see screenshot: http://i49.tinypic.com/2dwdvtj.png) could it perhaps be something to do with this line: "template="catalog/product/list.phtml" ?

Comment: just switch to default magento theme and check whether its working.If yes then the problem will be in the template file app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: Success haha! the products showed up when I disabled the theme and I've managed to locate the source of the problem in the theme. Thank you for all your help!!